# Why does my function render this way? It should render within the ExpansionPanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-mvc

I'm doing some code in Telerik with MVC, I'm trying to render a table inside an `ExpansionPanel`:

[Render the grid outside of the ExpansionPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njlDk.png)

Code of `ExpansionPanel`:

```
<div class="row">
    @(Html.Kendo().ExpansionPanel()
                  .Name("brazil")
                  .Title("Brazil")
                  .SubTitle("South America")
                  .Expanded(false)
                  .Content(RenderHello)
              )
</div>
```

Code of `RenderHello`:

```
@functions {
    void RenderHello()
    {
        @(
        Html.Kendo().Grid<CliroSorter.Models.OrdenDetalle>()
                        .Name("grid12") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(o => o.NumOrden).Title("Numero de orden").Width(100);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.CodProducto).Title("Producto").Width(100);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.Cantidad).Width(100);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.CodProveedor).Title("Proveedor").Width(100);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.NumTienda).Title("Tienda").Width(100);
                        })
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(5)
                    .Read(read => read.Action("ReadDetails", "N1"))
                )
                .Pageable()
                .Sortable()
           )
    }
}
```

I need the grid to render inside the `ExpansionPanel`.